# What does exc_breakpoint mean in debugging?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

- This bug show only ocassionally
  The bug in xcode shows

> exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt, subcode=0x0)

This is the screenshot of the bug:
[image]

Bonus: If anyone can tell me how to "copy" the error message it'll be appreciated

In immediate window the log says:

> 2012-06-04 12:08:17.097 BadgerNew[866:17003] Reachability Flag
>   Status:-R -----l- networkStatusForFlags

The code around the project is pretty much fool proof. I am very surprised that we have a bug there.

```
+(NSString *) Json_StringGetter:(NSString *) URL{
    CM(@"Json string getter");
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    DLog(@"request:%@",request);
    PO(URL);
    PO(request);

    __block NSError *error=nil;
    __block NSURLResponse *urlresponse=nil;
    __block NSData *response = nil;
    __block NSString *json_string=nil;

    //[Tools computeTimeWithName:FUNC block:^{
        response= [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error:&error];
        json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //}];

    if (error) {
        DLog(@"error at jsonparser:%@",urlresponse);
        DLog(@"error at jsonparser:%@",error);
        DLog(@"I break points here");
    }

    return json_string;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a stacktrace in see what is happening.

Comment: Well, I think [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest is pretty much robust. When things go wrong it'll just fill error. My concern is internet wasn't working well when it happened.

Comment: My issue was trying to reference a file that I had added to the project, but not added to the target bundle.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is I break when the URL is loading. That's why I got this issue.

It basically says that you press break point. If I just run the code without breaking this issue never show up.